# How to calculate the trajectory of a parabola on GoogleEarthPro given 3 geocoordinates?

Tags: curve-fitting, google-earth, curve

I am not a coder, I apologize, but I have attempted to solve this on my own but am confused as geocoordinates are given in (Latitude, Longitude) which seems to imply I need to input the coordinates as [y,x] into online 3 point conversion calculator to identify the parabolic equation (ex., y = ax^2 + bx = c).  I have 2 confirmed points (41.8794 N, 87.6238 W), (46.7988 N, 71.2247 W) and educated guess for third point (39.8259 N, 86.1858 W).  I need to see at what point the parabola would cross New Zealand or Australia with these given points or plotting for corrected 3rd point at a later time.  Thanks Everybody!
Even better if someone knows an application to Google Earth Pro that lay person can use.

Comment: Is this a question about programming? if yes, what exactly are you asking? Why parabola, maybe you are looking for a circle passing through those points?

Comment: Not about programming.  A circle might make sense.  Thank's for taking the time to respond.  I am on a treasure hunt and I thought it was necessary to graph a parabolic curve on the surface of the Earth but not having too much luck with that.  I will follow your lead and see how I can apply the idea of a circle.